# How have I incorrectly calculated the area A inside the curve $r =1$ and outside the curve $r = 2\cos(\theta)$

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I hope this isn't against guidelines but I want to show how I solved this on white paper, it might be clear where my logic went wrong in solving.

Find the are A of the region inside the curve $r = 1$ and outside the curve $r = 2cos(\theta)$

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Not checked all this through - but how do you go from $\cos^2(x)$ to $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)$ I would agree if you had $\cos(2x) = 2\cos^2 x - 1$

Comment: I've been trying to visualize the area that $0.5\int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\pi} (2\cos (\theta))^2$ represents and if that's the area that we want to take off. It doesn't seem like it.

Comment: Here's what I came up with there's no way that is going to be what we want to take off. Think about $\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} 0.5(2\cos (\theta))^2 d\theta$ represents. It represents the area of the top semi-circle. The best approach I can see is to split the area into parts.

Comment: @Chinny84 I thought that was the double angle identity?

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla Can't we just integrate from the first intersection point to π and since we know that's half of the area we need can't we can double that amount? That's the approach I am most comfortable with doing. But I need to learn the others too.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot integrate both over the interval $\left[\frac{\pi}{3},\pi\right]$.

The largest part is the quarter circle in the second quadrant which we know must have area equal to $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ but it can be easily verified:

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}\int_{\pi/2}^\pi 1\,d\theta=\left[\frac{\theta}{2}\right]_{\pi/2}^\pi=\frac{\pi}{4}
\end{equation}

It is only the part in quadrant I that is bounded by both functions:

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{2}\int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2}1-4\cos^2\theta\,d\theta&=& \text{ continue from here}\\
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: By the way, $\cos^2\theta=\dfrac{1+\cos(2\theta)}{2}$ not $\dfrac{1+\sin(2\theta)}{2}$ as you wrote on your paper.

Comment: Thank you! I see I had that ID wrong. Please can you explain why we cannot both integrate over pi/3 to pi? I thought since pi/3 is where it intersects then we can just start there and integrate till pi, and since that is the same area under the x-axis we could just double it? What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: The $r=2\cos\theta$ graph goes to $0$ at $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ so it does not form a lower bound for the region between $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ and $\pi$. In fact it crosses over into the fourth quadrant. So if you include $r=2\cos\theta$ on that interval you are actually subtracting that portion of the region lying in the third quadrant from the actual sum. Try just integrating from $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ to $\pi$ using both functions. You know you should get $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ but you get instead that value *minus* the area in quadrant IV.

Comment: To be very honest, I am totally confused by what you said. Why did you bring up 0 to π/2? what do you mean it does not form a lower bound for the region between π/2 to π, this statement confuses me, what do you mean by lower bound?

Comment: I did not bring up the interval $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, I said that $r=2\cos\theta=0$ when $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$. As far as upper and lower bounds in polar coordinates, think of a ray going out from the pole $(0,0)$. The first curve it encounters is the "lower bound" and the second curve it encounters is the "upper bound."  For $\frac{\pi}{2}\le\theta\le\pi$ there is no lower bound for the region, only the upper bound $r=1$. The $r=2\cos\theta$ is completely "out of the picture" over that range of $\theta$ values.  @Ahmed S. Attaalla's diagram explained it well, and with the correct answer.

Comment: I have made a desmos.com graph of the problem, but it is just a duplicate of your hand drawn diagram. Notice that what you are looking for is just two-thirds of the area of the circle minus the two red regions. So find the area of one of the red regions and subtract twice that amount from $\frac{2\pi}{3}$. That should give the correct answer.
    https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bmvphdj43l

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The area of the blue and yellow pieces together is,

$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\pi} \frac{1}{2}(1)^2 d\theta=\frac{\pi}{3}$$

The area of the blue piece by itself is,

$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{2}(2\cos (\theta))^2 d\theta$$

$$=\int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} 2\cos^2(\theta) d\theta$$

$$=\int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} 2\left(\frac{1+\cos(2\theta)}{2} \right) d\theta$$

$$=\frac{\pi}{6}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$$

Thus the area of the yellow piece is,

$$\frac{\pi}{3}-(\frac{\pi}{6}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4})=\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$$

The area you are interested in is twice this:

$$A=\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

Comment: Thank you, I feel like I still don't understand what I was doing wrong. In your answer I see how we area getting ALL that area with the first equation. But I don't understand how we are getting the blue piece by itself with the second equation, could you please explain more about that.

Comment: Please tell me what I did wrong. My idea was to integrate from the first intersection point till pi, therefore that would give me exactly half of the area, then I just doubled that area. For the integral I thought the idea would be, (wanted area minus not wanted area) . Then compute.

Comment: What happens (especially to $r=2\cos(\theta)$) when $\theta \in [\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$ are we bounded below by $r=2\cos(\theta)$ and above by $r=1$? @yre

Comment: The second integral gets the blue piece because the blue price is bounded below by $r=0$ and above by $r=2\cos(\theta)$ as $\theta$ ranges between $\frac{\pi}{3}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Sorry, still not understanding. When we rotate between pi/2 to pi, wouldn't there be no $2cos(\theta)$? Because pi/2 is where $r = 2cos(\theta)$ ends, the yellow is from 0 to to 2pi or a full circle right? There is something I am not getting here.

Comment: Isn't from pi/3 to -pi/3 only the stuff within yellow? so anything in between is only r = 2?

Comment: No from $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\pi$  you are tracing out the top of the semicircle $r=2\cos(\theta)$ (in a clockwise path). Look at the values you have in your table.

Comment: Why clockwise? I thought all of these polar graphs followed a strictly counter clockwise motion? Yeah, I am really not understanding at all, still thank you, I wish this made sense to me....