# Why does $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \ln(e^x - 1) = -\infty$ and not $1$?

Tags: calculus, limits

What does it mean for a limit to be approaching from the right? I know the graph of $\ln(x)$, and I understand that if $\ln(x)$ is being approached from the righthand side that means it's heading towards $-\infty$ but wouldn't it be like this:

$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\ln(e^{0^+}-1)$

I don't know what $e^{0^+}$ actually represents I think it would just be $e^0$ in that case, right?

So then,

\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 0^+}\ln(e^{0^+}-1)\\
\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \ln(e^{0} - 1)\\
\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \ln(1 - 1)\\
\lim_{x\to0^+}\ln0\end{align}

$\require{cancel}$
$\ln0=\cancel1$, right? But how is it $-\infty$?

Thank you

Comment: $\ln1=0$ and $\ln0=-\infty$

Comment: Recall that $\ln 0$ is undefined. It is not 1.

Comment: I believe you confused logarithm and exponential.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel thank you. So my computation was right? except for the last part? Also, ln(0) = -∞ but is this only when we are taking limits? Say we are just given the function f(0) = ln(x) that would be undefined? but since we are in a limit it's going to be -∞ solely because it's inside a limit?

Comment: _Yes._ $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: @ParclyTaxel so this is the reason it is -∞? I am not understanding if there is something more to this.

Comment: See the answer given.

Comment: When we have $x\to 0^+$, it means that $x$ is positive which is very close to $0$ and $e^{0^+}$ is nonsense. Rather we observe that $e^x$  becomes closed to $1$.

Comment: $\ln(1/n)=-\ln(n)$ , here with $n\to\infty$

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan I think I understand, so could it be thought of like this, e^(0.01), e^(0.001), e^(0.0001),.... so it's getting super close to 0 but not quite 0. So e^x it's getting super close 1 but not quite 1, so it's always going to be a little over the value of 1 so (super close to 1 MINUS 1), how does this warrant -∞?

Comment: "$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0^+}$" is just notation that means $x$ is approaching $0$ from the positive side.  So $x$ never takes on negative values.  In some cases this is important in order to avoid domain issues, like if you're evaluating $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0^+} \sqrt{x}$, or like in the problem you have here (because if $x$ takes on negative values, then $e^x-1 < 0$ and then $\ln(e^x-1)$ is undefined here).  And yes, in this case $\lim_{x\to0^+} e^x$ is just $e^0$.

Comment: @tilper so in this case, I can just think of it like evaluating $e^0$ none of that 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001,.... stuff? Just simply evaluate and notice that ln(0) is UND if by itself, but since it's inside a limit ln(0) actually means -∞?

Comment: Short answer: because $1$ is already the logarithm of $e$.

Comment: Well, $\lim_{x\to0^+} e^x = e^0 = 1$, sure, because direct substitution works fine there.  But for your exact problem you'll have to be more careful because direct substitution doesn't work since you end up with $\ln(0)$ which is undefined.  In order to evaluate $\lim_{x\to^0+} \ln(e^x-1)$, you'll want to think about what $\ln(e^x-1)$ looks like as $x$ approaches $0$ from the positive side.  And since $x$ approaching $0$ from the positive side means $e^x-1$ approaches $0$ from the positive side, then you're basically trying to determine what happens with $\ln(e^x-1)$ as $e^x-1$ approaches $0$

Comment: from the positive side.  Say $t = e^x-1$.  Then you're asking what's happening with $\ln t$ as $t \to 0^+$.  For this you can simply look at the graph of $y = \ln t$ and see that as $t \to 0^+$, we have $y \to -\infty$.  So the limit you're looking for is $-\infty$.

Comment: @tilper so this essentially just comes down to shrinking values closer and closer and closer to 0 but not quite 0, so it's consistently APPROACHING a number close to 0 and since this is wrapped up inside the ln(x) we look at that functions behavior, which when it's approaching closer and closer to 0 then it's heading off towards -∞?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  And that's exactly how all limits are in general.  It's just that some limits are simple enough that direct evaluation will work (like $\lim_{x\to0^+} \sqrt x$) but most of the time it won't, and you'll want to think of those essentially as you described there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, $\ln(0)$ is undefined. First, consider that $e^x$ is the inverse function of $\ln(x),$ that is, $\ln(e^x)=x.$ The range of $e^x,$ is $(0,\infty).$ This indicates that $e^x\ne0,$ for any $x.$ Therefore $0$ is not in the domain of $\ln(x),$ so $\ln(0)$ is undefined.

As to the limit:

Since  $e^0=1,$ so $$\lim_{x^+\to 0} e^{x}-1=0.$$

We have that the composition of continuous functions is continuous (at least here we are continuous to the right of zero with $\ln$). So we get

$$\lim_{x^+\to 0}\ln( e^{x}-1)=\lim_{y\to 0^+}~\ln(y)=-\infty.$$

Back to the domain and range stuff. The idea for this limit comes from

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty} e^x=0.$$

Which is true as a limit, but this doesn't mean $e^x$ is ever actually zero.

Comment: Thank you. Isn't the function ln(0) undefined, but when it's inside a limit either approaching left side or right side or infinity then it's -∞? So if it were a say f(0) = ln(x) that's UND, but if it's lim x->∞ ln(0) then it's -∞ ?

Comment: $\ln(0)$ is undefined, but this doesn't meant that the limit is undefined. 

A limit represents the quantity which your function is approaching as $x\to 0^+,$ not the value it ever actually takes on.

Comment: Is it because e^x is really something like e^(0.01), e^(0.001), e^(0.001), e^(0.0001),.... so it's getting very close to 0, therefore e^x is getting super to close to 1, but not quite 1. Therefore (super close to 1 MINUS 1) means we are consistently approach something very small, or therefore approaching 0, and this is the limit process, it's approaching 0 and went ln(x) approaches 0 that means it's approaching -∞?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea of a limit.

Comment: So I can see it visually like: 0.01 - 1, 0.001 - 1, 0.0001 - 1, 0.00001 - 1,.... So each increment closer, we are in turn getting close to 0, as the limit gets consistently closer to 0 the graph of ln(x) is in turn getting consistently closer to -∞?

Comment: It'll never actually reach it, since $-\infty$ isn't a real number, and since $\ln(0)$ isn't defined. But you're correct that it will approach $-\infty.$

Comment: Great! Feel free to upvote and click the check mark.

Comment: Any chance you are good with polar graphs too? I am having trouble understanding why my limits of integration are wrong. Can I show you the question?

Comment: As long as it is posted as another question and not a comment yes.

Comment: Sure thing!
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2274081/how-have-i-incorrectly-calculated-the-area-a-inside-the-curve-r-1-and-outside

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just a side note as why $1$ isn't the right sided limit at $x=0$.

In this case $lim_{x\to a+}=L $ then $ \forall \epsilon \gt 0 \  \exists \delta \ \gt 0 $ such that  $0 \lt x-a\lt \delta$ implies $|f(x)-L| \lt \epsilon$.

So if limit $L=1$ then we have $$0 \lt x \lt \delta \ \implies \ |ln(e^x-1)-1|\lt \epsilon$$

This means considered as sets, $\{x:0\lt x \lt \delta\}\  \subseteq \{x: |ln(e^x-1)-1|\lt \epsilon\}$

The second set can be expressed as $$\{ x: ln(1+e^{1-\epsilon}) \lt x \lt ln(1+e)\} \cup\{x: ln(1+x) \le x \lt ln(e^{\epsilon +1}+1) \}$$

But solving for $x$ we see $$\{x: 0 \lt x \lt \delta \} \nsubseteq \{ x: ln(e^{1-\epsilon}+1) \lt x \lt ln(e^{1+\epsilon}+1) \} \ \forall \epsilon \forall \delta$$

Thus $1$ cannot be the limit from the right at $x=0$.